# Proof of 2 Triangles in a Paralellogram

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the given figure $PSDA$ is a parallelogram. Points $Q$ and $R$ are such that $PQ=QR=RS$ and $PA\parallel QB \parallel RC$. Prove that $\mathrm{ar}(PQE)=\mathrm{ar}(CFD)$.

**Note:** this is high-school homework problem.

Comment: Can you relate the area of $\triangle PQE$ and $\triangle PSD$?

Comment: However, $QE \parallel SD$, right? Can you relate the angles of those two triangles (i.e. pair them up)?

Comment: That's one pair, what about two more? Do you know what happens if [a line crosses two parallel lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Parallel_transversal.svg)?

Comment: Ok, I put it another way, $|\angle PQE| = |\angle PSD|$ because $QE \parallel SD$. Did you have such a theorem in your class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7869/discussion-between-dtldarek-and-click-upvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the chat discussion:

---

Triangles $\triangle PQE$ and $ \triangle DCF$ are similar because

$$\triangle PQE \sim \triangle PSD \sim \triangle DAP \sim DCF.$$

Moreover, $PQ = RS = CD$, thus $\triangle PQE$ and $ \triangle DCF$ are congruent and as such have the same area.